# Logic to detect if a GNU screen is running

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

For a project I am developing I would like to detect if a screen is running as the current user, attached or detached. I would like an approach that uses the minimal number of processes and will be portable across distros/unix based OSes.

Option 1

```
ps -U $USER|grep screen|grep -v grep &>/dev/null && screen-yes
```

This appears quite untidy but it does do the job. the additional grep was needed for Darwin but not CentOS, is there a better way?

Option 2

```
screen -list|egrep '(There is a screen on|There are screens on)' &>/dev/null && screen-yes
```

This directly uses the screen command, but due to the relatively human style output that large regex is needed.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If the reason you want to check is that you want to start a new session if none is running yet, but reconnect to an already-existing one it there is, note that you can run screen with some options to do just that...

Comment: Yes, to achieve this: screen -D -R . I wanted to detect screen for this feature: https://github.com/benvaljean/bgrc/wiki/Post-login%20icons

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the return code from screen. It is true if there are screens, and false if there are none.

```
screen -list >/dev/null && screen-yes
```

Comment: Not in my testing: screen-list returns 1 if there are screens or no screens. What system are you running?

Comment: That's unfortunate, as I'd expect gnu screen to work the same everywhere. I have screen-4.3.1 on fedora 21. Also ok on 4.01.0 raspberry pi debian.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer for any version of Screen from the 21st century. Just from a very cursory and very inexpert review of [the source](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=screen), versions prior to about 3.2 may have exhibited this behavior. But that would be a very old `screen` indeed—like 1991 old. Newer versions _should_ exhibit the described behavior and exit with status 1 only if no existing sessions are found.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be a variation of option 1:

```
ps -U $USER | grep [s]creen &>/dev/null && screen-yes
```

The square brackets around the first letter of the `screen` string use shell glob magic to avoid getting the `grep` command returned in the output. Same net effect, one less `grep` command.

Comment: That does work. I also found I could use pgrep in this way: pgrep -U $USER screen &>/dev/null && echo yes  . I am not sure how portable pgrep is compared to ps. I can see pgrep on Debian 5 (old) though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if test ! -z "$STY" 
then    
    echo "I am running in GNU Screen"
fi
```

---

Is a quick solution which does not require external programs.

Comment: The $STY variable is present only if the shell is inside a screen. The requirement is to ascertain if there are any screens running for $USER on the host.

Comment: Doesn't meet the requirements of the OP's question, but was **exactly what I was looking for**. This wasn't super obvious, even after scrutinizing the manual page. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep -U $USER screen &>/dev/null && screen-yes
```

This does not require any additional processes and solves the problem with relatively long regex with option 1, using >1 process with option 2. I found pgrep on some fairly old systems so it should be portable.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 (at least) due to kscreen_backend_launcher